# What are the rules of a Spiritual Weapon occupying a square?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

So we've run into this problem a few times with our D&D 5E group. The problem breaks down as such: We have a spectral weapon from our cleric, we've used an icon to represent it. The square that the weapon occupies counts as what? Does it count as a character in that square? Does it block enemies from moving into it? Does it impede them (difficult terrain?) if it doesn't block? Basically:

**If a spectral weapon from the spell *Spiritual Weapon* is on a square what are the rules as written on enemies moving on that square?**

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I won't reproduce them all here, but all of the rules about occupying a square refer to creatures, and the weapon created by *Spiritual Weapon* isn't a creature.

> You create a floating, spectral weapon[...]

So it shouldn't hinder creatures moving through or even standing its square in the slightest.

Comment: I have run into this scenario before as DM, and while it is true that the Spiritual Weapon does not occupy space, it is still a floating, attacking weapon. As such, it might be fun to RP monsters as being too wary to pass thru its space. Only my BBEGs and magic experts know well enough to walk thru a Spiritual Weapon's space. :)

Answer (score 7):

## Spiritual Weapon does not occupy a square

The rules about occupying squares only talk about creatures.

Additionally, [Jeremy Crawford](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/958085307898806272) has clarified to verify this as explicitly true:

> A spiritual weapon doesn't pass through walls. It also doesn't occupy its space; it's not a creature, and it's not described as being large enough to fill its space.